# Write file to web application context folder

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications

I have a web application running on tomcat. I upload a file to the server using commons-fileupload and commons-io (The apache libraries). The file that i upload is stored in temporary folder somewhere around the system ( i have the path). I want to copy that file to a file within the webapp (context) folder because i need it related to the application, but not the architecture, operation system and etc. So far i know the path to the temporary file.

```
 ServletFileUpload servletFileUpload = new ServletFileUpload();
        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(req);
        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

// Configure a repository (to ensure a secure temp location is used)
        ServletContext servletContext = this.getServletConfig().getServletContext();
        File repository = (File) servletContext.getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");
        factory.setRepository(repository);

// Create a new file upload handler
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

// Parse the request
        try {
            List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(req);
            System.out.println(items);
        } catch (FileUploadException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is what i got in my servlet so far

Comment: I think i found the gem :). servletContext.getRealPath("/") and it returns the path to the context :)

Comment: Be aware that getRealPath can return null

Comment: Well yeah i left that option

Comment: Btw i still collect suggestions on how to uplaod img

Comment: This is generally a Bad Idea™ -- There's no guarantee that there is a writable file system in a web application. You could be running from an unexploded war or remote network resource.